# Tests with Karma not finishing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I have been trying to run some tests with karma but have not been able to get it to work. After trying to get it to work with my application, I tried running it with the most simple possible test, and yet, it still does not finish.

Here is my karma.conf.js file:

```
    // Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      // 'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      // // 'app/bower_components/angular/angular-mocks.js',
      // 'app/scripts/*.js',
      // 'app/scripts/controllers/main.js',
      // // 'test/mock/**/*.js',
      // 'test/spec/**/*.js',
      // // 'app/scripts/**/*.js,'
      'testing.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: ['angular-scenario.js'],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

and here is the testing.js file :

```
describe("hello", function(){
    it("Should fail automatically", function(){
        expect(false).toBe(true)
    });
});
```

The result I get without fail is:

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.7.5)]: Connected on socket dGANukHhgkPC3YyhyUrU
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.7.5)]: Connected on socket HC8iGMv-VmeYX2UAyUrV
```

It never seems to go on and tell me how many of my tests succeeded or not.

Thanks for all of the help. Hopefully I will have some hair left at the end of this, haha.

Comment: if that's all the output you got, it seems like Chrome isn't executing any tests. I faced a similar issue but I forgot how I solved it. Try using some other browser? You might want to try out PhantomJS and see what you get

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

`single_run : true` means run the tests once *and exit*.

`single_run : false` means *don't exit* (this is not obvious).

`autowatch : true` means trigger running tests when a file changes.

If you have *both* `autowatch` and `single_run` set to false (like you do), then running

`karma start`

will just have karma initialize and wait for something to trigger it to run.

In order to trigger running the tests you need to open a new console and do

`karma run`

(Or set one of the above mentioned flags to 'true')

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  I ended up installing the version of node that was suggested here: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/intro/faq.html. So now, I am running node.js version 0.10.38 with karma server version 1.4.28 and Chrome is happy with that.